# Countdown timer for discounted Woocommerce products without plugins

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, countdowntimer

I'm going to create a countdown timer for Woocommerce discounted products without using the plugin on my website theme and I'm looking for code to do it for me using JavaScript or php
please help....!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For woocommerce countdown timer need to create custom fields and a custom time libraries or you can create own. Please look at the demo below

https://axlmulat.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-tutorial-how-to-add-sales-countdown-timer-in-the-product-page/

Comment: The code worked correctly. thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct what you want?

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var count = 24*60*60; //24h
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
  count--;
  var seconds = count % 60 ;
  var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60) % 60;
  var hours   = Math.floor(count / (60*60)) % 24;
  if(count > 0) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "done"
    clearInterval(myVar);
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need a code to show the timer based on the Wokamers product's expiration date.